# Canvas font size

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to use a small font on my Canvas.
If you use the code below for the font, the color appears to be grey for font size less than 9px? How to make the font appear black and still use font size 8px or less? Please change the ctx.font with New code 1 or new code 2:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_font

New Code 1:

```
ctx.font = "9px helvetica-neue, sans-serif";
```

New Code 2:

```
ctx.font = "8px helvetica-neue, sans-serif";
```

Comment: When I try out your code on that page, it looks black regardless of the font size (although the smaller it gets, the harder it is to distinguish). I've not done much with HTML5, but have you tried this in different browsers (IE/Edge, Chrome, Safari, etc)? I'm just wondering if it's a quirk of a particular browser which makes assumptions about what colour you want the text to be, depending on the size.

Comment: Cant see the problem. It would help if you provided a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that font size changing a color. I never seen it in my life so far and most likely it doesn't. The quick solution for you would be this code: `ctx.fillStyle = 'black'` just to be sure that is black anyways! But as I said, it is not changing a default text color.